# How to get normalised laplacian matrix using armadillo

Tags: c++, graph, linear-algebra, armadillo

Can anybody please tell me what is the equivalent of the following operation in Armadillo linear algebra package 
 L = D^-0.5 * A * D^-0.5

## In general how to compute A^n or A^-0.5 in Armadillo where A is a square matrix

Comment: the [sqrtmat()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sqrtmat) function might be useful

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way to do it

```
 mat K1,K2;
 K1.load(argv[1],auto_detect);
 colvec c = sum(K1,1);
 mat D = diagmat(c);
 mat D1 = pow(inv(D),0.5);
 mat I(10,10);I.eye();
 mat L = I - D1*K1*D1;
```

## is there any other simpler way ?